# Linux - Bash - Copying multi-line strings from source to terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing notes as I prepare a system so I have something to follow if/when I need to prepare another system. Also I am hoping to use these notes and implement into a puppet configuration at some point.

I am trying to write multi-line bash commands, but when I copy and paste from my IDE (aptana) into the terminal, I get weird behavior and the commands never execute, even though when I step back in history the multi-line command looks like I entered it manually.

My question is, how can I save the commands in a multi-line format so I can quickly copy and paste into the terminal?

Example:

```
$ "mkdir -p /var/log/php && \
 chown -R apache /var/log/php && \ 
 chgrp -R webdev /var/log/php && \
 chmod -R 775 /var/log/php && \ 
 touch /var/log/php/oops.log"

touch /var/log/php/oops.log: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash control operators (such as `&&`) do NOT require a " \" to concatenate lines together. You also do not need to quote your script. The re-factored version would be:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/php && 
/bin/chown -R apache /var/log/php &&  
/bin/chgrp -R webdev /var/log/php && 
/bin/chmod -R 775 /var/log/php &&  
touch /var/log/php/oops.log
```

Cutting and pasting that script in a shell should work.

Comment: Interesting, I thought I tried this combo, apparently not. Your solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exec`:

```
$ exec <<< "echo hello world"
```

**BUT** keep in mind, it will exit your current shell once done. You could address this by spawning a new shell:

```
$ bash -s <<< "echo hello world"
```

Also, you could make it a bash script. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /var/log/php
chown -R apache /var/log/php
chgrp -R webdev /var/log/php
chmod -R 775 /var/log/php
touch /var/log/php/oops.log
```

You could do something like:

```
$ cat >> ~/script.sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /var/log/php
chown -R apache /var/log/php
chgrp -R webdev /var/log/php
chmod -R 775 /var/log/php
touch /var/log/php/oops.log
<CTRL+D>
$ . ~/script.sh
```

Comment: Was considering that... Just wanted to see if it was possible to copy and paste straight into the terminal first.

Comment: Ah, you could address the spawning by opening a new shell. Thanks @Pascal.Charest.

Answer (score 0):

You simply do the first four commands by doing...

```
$ install -o apache -g webdev -m 0755 -d /var/log/php
```

This will create a directory `/var/log/php` with owner `apache` group `webdev` and permission `0755`.